# Webpage source code in Iframe with the help of php

Tags: php, html, iframe

I want to show a url's source code in iframe tag. How to do it ?
For example, I have this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php $content = @file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

How to show $content in iframe ?

Comment: Why do you need an `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code:
EDIT: iframe version..:

save this source as **getsource.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <pre>
        <?= htmlentities( @file_get_contents($_GET['url'])); ?>
        </pre>    
</div>
</body>
```

then use your iframe somewhere on a different page and add src to getsource.php with url variable:

```
<iframe src="getsource.php?url=http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

This might be not safe, but i think the htmlentities will prevent xss attacks.

Comment: @Abadis Not really.. If he hadn't used the htmlentities(), an XSS attack wouldn't be possible anyway. (If so, please comment how.) This is because the source code isn't processed with PHP, only gathered. +1 for good and straight forwards answer.

Comment: Why would you want it in an iframe?

Comment: Iframes aren't allowed anymore (HTML5)

Comment: @50ndr33 - [HTML5 - The iframe elment](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element)

Comment: an iframe need an address.put the address on a.php and in a.php write the code given to you.for xss attack i have to test!!!

Comment: Aren't PHP short tags bad practice?

Comment: [Actually, looks like `<?=` is a special case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6064813/102441)

Comment: @Eric `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo ` You would need short tags to be turned on in `php.ini`. So you could also use `<?`, which is not good practice.

Comment: yes, <?= is a short tag for printing. is the same as <?php echo ... - but if short tags are disabled the code might not work, so you should use <?php echo $blah..?>

Comment: @50ndr33, @qxxx: Did you read the post I linked to about `<?=`? - _"Starting PHP 5.4 the echo shortcut is a separate issue from short tags, as they will always be enabled"_

Comment: @50ndr33 really? wow, didn't know that :) awesome! will read your linked post

Comment: @Eric PHP 5.4 isn't yet supported by many vendors, so there will be a good chance that it will not work for him. It is always good to be on the safe side. If he asks a question like this, he probably didn't know about those short tags eighter...

Comment: @50ndr33 oops... sorry, i mean the post from "Eric" http://stackoverflow.com/a/6064813/102441 ;)

Comment: @qxxx can't i combine the both in one file ?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to the `main page`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Source Code</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="phpscript.php">Your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>
</body>
```

Put this in `phpscript.php`:

```
<pre>
<?php echo htmlentities( @file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/")); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll have to have a separate page with an iframe, whose `src` points to this page.

Though, may I ask why you have you use an iframe? It seems like you can just show it in a scrollable "div".

Comment: i want to show source code of a webpage to its owner when he/she clicks on the link 'see code' with some highlighted code.